# why Connection Refused error on simple Docker + nginx configuration?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY devops/nginx_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 8080
```

and a `devops/nginx_proxy.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  client_max_body_size        32M;
  underscores_in_headers      on;
}
```

Running the Dockerfile with `docker run -p 8080:80 test` and then testing with `curl http://localhost/`, I see this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Even more curious, `curl http://localhost:8080/` returns this:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Docker you can [bind](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) containers ports to host ports using the `-p` option.

### General rule

```
docker run -p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
```

### Bind container 8080 port to the 80 of the host

```
docker run -p 80:8080 test
```

> Ports which are not bound to the host (i.e., -p 80:80 instead of -p 127.0.0.1:80:80) are accessible from the outside

### Bind the port limiting the access to localhost

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 test
```